# Autofac: Reference from a SingleInstance'd type to a HttpRequestScoped

Tags: asp.net, scope, autofac

I've got an application where a shared object needs a reference to a per-request object.

```
Shared:      Engine
                |
Per Req:  IExtensions()
                |
             Request
```

If i try to inject the `IExtensions` directly into the constructor of `Engine`, even as `Lazy(Of IExtension)`, I get a "No scope matching [Request] is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested." exception when it tries to instantiate each `IExtension`.

How can I create a HttpRequestScoped instance and then inject it into a shared instance?

Would it be considered good practice to set it in the `Request`'s factory (and therefore inject `Engine` into `RequestFactory`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the shared lifetime requirements of `Engine` you cannot inject request-scoped extensions into it. What you could have is a method or property on Engine that will actively resolve a collection of extensions from the current request scope.

So first, let `Engine` take a constructor dependency:

```
public class Engine
{
    public Engine(..., Func<IExtensions> extensionsPerRequest) 
    {
        _extensionsPerRequest = extensionsPerRequest;
    }


    public IExtensions Extensions
    {
       get { return _extensionsPerRequest(); }
    }
 }
```

And then, in your Autofac registration:

```
builder.Register<Func<IExtensions>>(c => RequestContainer.Resolve<IExtensions>());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.
It took me a little fiddling to find out that in VB I needed to construct a function myself in the Register() call, but now it works :D
The lambda for the Autofac registration is: Function(c) New Func(Of IExtensions)(Function() RequestContainer.Resolve(Of IExtensions)())