# Orchard CMS, Autofac Relationship

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, orchardcms, autofac

I am trying to create a "A(UserManager) needs to create instances of B(UserClient)" relationship (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) where B(UserClient) needs a HttpSessionStateBase..

UserClient

```
public class UserClient : IUserClient
    {
        public UserClient(HttpSessionStateBase session)
        {
             //...
        }

        //...
    }
```

UserManager

```
public class UserManager : IUserManager
    {
        private readonly Func<IUserClient> userClientPerRequest;
        private IUserClient UserClient
        {
            get
            {
                return userClientPerRequest();
            }
        }

        public UserManager(Func<IUserClient> userClientPerRequest)
        {
            this.userClientPerRequest = userClientPerRequest;
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            UserClient.DoStuff();
        }
```

This is where is register autofac stuff

```
public class MyModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            builder.RegisterType<UserManager>().As<IUserManager>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<UserClient>().As<IUserClient>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());


            //If i try this, i get Error 1 (printing errors after this code-block)
            builder.Register<Func<IUserClient>>(c => c.Resolve<IUserClient>);

            //If i try this, i get Error 2                
            builder.Register<Func<IUserClient>>(c => {
            var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return ctx.Resolve<IUserClient>;                
            });

            //If i try this, well i always get null from GetService..
            builder.Register<Func<IUserClient>>(c =>            
            DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserClient>);
        }
```

Looking at [Autofac: Reference from a SingleInstance'd type to a HttpRequestScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599566/autofac-reference-from-a-singleinstanced-type-to-a-httprequestscoped?rq=1) , they use some `RequestContainer` but i can find no such thing. :)

Error 1

```
This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components from.
```

Error 2

```
No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being reqested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.
```

I have tried switching `.InstancePerHttpRequest()` to `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` and a whole other different stuff.. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding Autofac registrations manually in Orchard, use `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("shell")`, if you need a singleton or `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("work")`, if you need per-request instance.

I'm not sure if `HttpSessionStateBase` ctor argument can actually be resolved from the container. You could put `IHttpContextAccessor` there instead and use it to access the session state object inside `IUserClient` implementation.

And as Jim Bolla suggested - `Func<IUserClient>` ([factory](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories)) is already available out of the box.

Comment: Ah great. 
However if i change it to InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope i get "Error 2" but this time its coming from inside OrchardFramework.DLL!Orchard.ContentManager.DefaultContentManager.Handlers.get().. Shouldnt the HttpSessionStateBase work when im using "AutofacWebTypesModule" ?

Comment: It seems to be working fine with IHttpContextAccessor and without AutofacWebTypesModule.. success!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do either of those registrations. Because of [Relationship Types](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes), `Func<IUserClient>` should already be available to you.

Comment: You seem to be correct! However i still get Error 2 from the 
"return userClientPerRequest();"-line.

Comment: I think the problem is that UserManager is SingleInstance, therefore it and its dependencies will be created outsite of an Http context.

Comment: Even if i set UserManager to InstancePerHttpRequest, i get the same error where the UserManager is created. But i thought UserManager could be single instance because it would create a new UserClient per httprequest? Perhaps that was not correct :)